# Compilation error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I am trying to insert data into MySQL and I'm getting an error:

> cannot find symbol c

```
import java.sql.*;

class Insert{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/db","ravi","ravi");
            //showing error in the below statement at c
            Statement stmt = c.CreateStatement();
            int result=stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into emp values(3,'david',33) ");
            System.out.println("success");
            c.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: typo: `c.createStatement();`....

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's `c.createStatement()` and not `c.CreateStatement()`.

You need to make that `c` to lowercase in the method name `createStatement()`

Comment: getting this:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationException: communication link failure
the last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.the drivier has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Make sure you've turned on the MySQL server.

Comment: yes it is on . i m able to retrieve data from database(another program) . but when i m trying to insert using above code . i am getting the above message.

Comment: You sure you have a table named `emp`?

Comment: yes  and i m able to retrieve data using select * from that table in another program .

Comment: Check your mysql link, id and password. And then tell me if it is right but still not working. Especially if your mysql server is really running on port number 3036

Comment: thanks @aditya , my sql is running at port 3306 .